# Create string from array?

Tags: php

I remember there was an easy way without a for each to reconstruct an array into a string.

EG:

```
1 > my
2 > name
3 > is
4 > sam
```

into
`$string = "my name is sam"` (with spaces in between).

How was this done with php?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the string:

```
$array = array("my", "name", "is", "sam");
$string = implode(' ', $array);
echo $string; // "my name is sam"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php

$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

print $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone

?>
```

Comment: Or to print one by line: `$one_per_line = implode(PHP_EOL, $array);`

Answer (score 2):

You should use the implode method. You can read more about it on the following link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php.

Your code would be something like:

```
$string = implode(" ", $array);
```